# How to delimit string(s) and convert to column headers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, text, dynamic, csv

How can you take a string(s) and convert to a column (dynamically as the source string(s) will change):

Example:

```
(select *
 from table 
 inner join
    (select column1, [dynamic field] from table) as dynamic_data
 on table.column1 = dynamic_data.column1)


Column1
------
a,b,c
c,d,e
a,f,e
```

to this

```
column1 a b c d e f
-------------------
a,b,c  |x|x|x| | | |
c,d,e  | | |x|x|x| |
a,f,e  |x| | | |x|x|
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Standard version 12

Comment: The best way would be to fix the design and stop storing delimited strings. It violates 1NF and is nothing but painful. Given the nature of this being dynamic you are going to need dynamic sql if you stick with this architecture.

Comment: The delimited string is out of my control, so it will stay that way.  Was hoping some sort of pivot approach might do it, just don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `like` and `case`:

```
select column1,
       (case when ',' + column1 + ',' like '%,a,%' then 'x' end) as a,
       (case when ',' + column1 + ',' like '%,b,%' then 'x' end) as b,
       (case when ',' + column1 + ',' like '%,c,%' then 'x' end) as c,
       (case when ',' + column1 + ',' like '%,d,%' then 'x' end) as d,
       (case when ',' + column1 + ',' like '%,e,%' then 'x' end) as e,
       (case when ',' + column1 + ',' like '%,f,%' then 'x' end) as f
from t;
```

I am not sure why "dynamic" is necessary.  The issue isn't the source strings, but the destination columns.  If you need those to match the source strings, then you do need to use dynamic SQL . . . and that seems rather complicated.

EDIT:

The heart of the dynamic SQL is putting together the `case` expressions.  You can do this using `string_split()` and `string_agg()` (or equivalent functions in older versions of SQL Server):

```
select string_agg(replace('      (case when '','' + column1 + '','' like ''%,[value],%'' then ''x'' end) as [value]', '[value]', value), '
'
                 ) within group (order by value) as cols
from (select distinct value
      from t cross apply
           string_split(t.column1, ',')
     ) t
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=93ef6e78c5c75ff10cca8745a7cd5fa1) is a db<>fiddle.

I'll let you construct the rest of the query.

Comment: It needs to be dynamic as the values in column1 are random, the new columns are dynamically created based on those values.

Comment: @hooch You should think long and hard about this dynamic approach. You will likely struggle to make use of such a resultset. As the number of possible values in your source code increases, the more unwieldly the code and resultset become. You use single character values in your sample data - what if your values have multiple characters?